# I tried changing the preprocessing part of the pymc code but when I unscales the data it uses the default standardscaler(). how can I change the code

Tags: bayesian, pymc

I was using the following code for transformation in pymc marketing package,

```
class StandardizeTarget:

target_transformer: Pipeline

@preprocessing_method_y
def standardize_target_data(self, data: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    target_vector = data.reshape(-1, 1)
    transformers = [("scaler", StandardScaler())]
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps=transformers)
    self.target_transformer: Pipeline = pipeline.fit(X=target_vector)
    data = self.target_transformer.transform(X=target_vector).flatten()
    return data
```

But for certain reasons I needed to change the code into the following,

```
class AbsStandardizeTarget:

target_transformer: Pipeline

@preprocessing_method_y
def standardize_target_data(self, data: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    target_vector = data.reshape(-1, 1)
    transformers = [("scaler", StandardScaler())]
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps=transformers)
    self.target_transformer: Pipeline = pipeline.fit(X=target_vector)
    data = self.target_transformer.transform(X=target_vector).flatten()
    data = np.abs(data)
    return data
```

Now I want to unscale the data again using the folloing code again,

```
if original_scale:

            all_contributions_over_time = pd.DataFrame(
                data=self.get_target_transformer().inverse_transform(
                    all_contributions_over_time
                ),
                columns=all_contributions_over_time.columns,
                index=all_contributions_over_time.index,
            )
            all_contributions_over_time.columns = (
                all_contributions_over_time.columns.map(
                    lambda x: f"channel_{x}" if isinstance(x, int) else x
                )
            )
```

But here the code self.get_target_transformer() is unscaling the data using standardscaler() function which is inbuilt but not using the function I have defined. How can I change the code so that I get the original unscaled data back.